# Solid background in MS word document

Tags: microsoft-word, watermark

I need to use a photograph as a background for a MS Word document but I need it to be solid, not faded/watermarked. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Which version of word do you use? Is it a .doc or docs?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an image's 'Text Wrapping' settings to achieve this without worrying about utilising the 'watermark' settings. Depending on your version of Office, the path to get to these settings may be a little bit different, however here's how to do it in Office 2013:

1. Insert the image
2. Select your image, and go to the 'Format' tab under Picture Tools
3. Click 'Position', and 'More Layout Options':
   [image: Position Options]
4. Under the 'Text Wrapping' heading, change the picture to be 'Behind Text':
   [image: Text Wrapping - Behind Text]
5. Click 'OK' to exit the dialog window
6. Click and Drag to position your image under your text:
   [image: Image under text]